# Postgres copy command adding extra backslash "\"

Tags: postgresql, copy, backup, pg-dump

I am trying to copy jsonb type of data into a file.

```
\copy (select myjsonbcolumn from mytable where time > timestamp '2021-05-01 00:00:00') to '/home/ubuntu/jsobdata.ndjson';
```

Now this jsonb data have `\`' within it. e.g.,

```
{"ID": "123","Body": "<p><a href=\"https://google.com\">Lorem ipsum</a></p>\n<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum </p>"}
```

Now the above copy command adds an extra "" to it, which transforms into below

```
{"ID": "123","Body": "<p><a href=\\"https://google.com\\">Lorem ipsum</a></p>\\n<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum </p>"}
```

Is there a way to notify not to add extra `\`? Because this huge data, more than 200GB and to replace those extra `\` will take a lot of time via file processing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the default output format of `COPY`, which is `text`, treats the backslash as an escape character, so it must be doubled. Use the `csv` format and set quote characters and delimiter to characters that do not occur in your data, for example

```
\copy (SELECT ...) TO '...' (FORMAT 'csv', QUOTE E'\u0007', DELIMITER E'\u0008')
```